# What does `-e .` in requirements.txt do?

Tags: python, pip, requirements.txt

From: https://github.com/brandon-rhodes/luca/blob/master/requirements.txt

```
ansi2html
pytest
sphinx
tox
-e .
```

What does the last line, `-e .`, do?

Comment: It installs the package as [editable](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#install-editable)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Looking at the [doc](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#cmdoption-e) the "-e" option indicates

> -e, --editable <path/url>
>
> Install a project in editable mode (i.e. >setuptools “develop mode”) from a >local project path or a VCS url.

So the dot indicates the path, i.e the actual directory (see [this](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.linfo.org/dot_slash.html&ved=0ahUKEwjxpvzItOzbAhVSC-wKHR6ABdMQFggoMAE&usg=AOvVaw2H3NsU-AOjsFLggZ6o_N6N) for more information).

Comment: Boo, broken link...