# how do I pip install something in editable mode using a requirements.txt file?

Tags: python, pip

I tried:

```
pip install -er meta-dataset/requirements.txt
```

doesn't work:

```
(meta_learning) brandomiranda~/diversity-for-predictive-success-of-meta-learning ❯ pip install -er meta-dataset/requirements.txt
ERROR: Invalid requirement: 'meta-dataset/requirements.txt'
Hint: It looks like a path. The path does exist. The argument you provided (meta-dataset/requirements.txt) appears to be a requirements file. If that is the case, use the '-r' flag to install the packages specified within it.
```

how to fix it?

related: [What does `-e .` in requirements.txt do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51010251/what-does-e-in-requirements-txt-do)

Answer (score 1):

Seems this works (when submoduling so they are found in the super parent dir):

```
pip install -r meta-dataset/requirements.txt -e meta-dataset
```

though it's weird we have to specify meta-dataset twice. You might have to change the paths depending where your stuff is e.g.

```
pip install -r $HOME/meta-dataset/requirements.txt -e $HOME/meta-dataset
```

your proj also needs a `setup.py` file...which is odd due to the requirements.txt. One soln could be to merge the reqs and put everything in the setup.py (so that it's not specified twice with potentially unmatching versions of reqs).

Comment: That's a bit more complicated than necessary. You can just add a line like `--editable .` directly in the `requirements.txt` file.

Comment: @wim feel free to provide your answer! I did comment my answer looked strange to me e.g. saying something twice. Btw, one might not want to always install in editable even when using a requirements.txt